# Adding multiple jquery datepicker functions together

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've been wracking my brain on how to do this and I've tried all sorts of combinations but to no avail.

I can find many many examples of how to insert single functions into a jquery date picker, so you can suppress certain dates from being picked, or change the date format etc but I can't find examples of how to combine them.

I have:

```
$(function() {
$( "#element_94_datepick" ).datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
}
});
});
```

This is working great for suppressing the dates that I don't need.
I however, want to add:

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

I've tried:

```
$(function() {
$( "#element_94_datepick" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
}
});
});
```

That broke the picker altogether

And:

```
$(function() {
$( "#element_94_datepick" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$( "#element_94_datepick" ).datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
}
});
});
```

Which also broke it (In both cases, the date picker didn't show up at all until I removed the changed code.

Can someone tell me how I can get these two functions to play nicely together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, since there are multiple properties to the options object they have to be separated by a `,`

```
$(function () {
    $("#element_94_datepick").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',//missed , here
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
        }
    });
});
```

Also the condition can be reduced to

```
$(function () {
    $("#element_94_datepick").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',//missed , here
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [day == 0];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, so after I posted my question, some similar questions appeared under the "related" section on the right. One user had multiple functions in their datepicker, and I found that they were using a comma to seperate the features like this:


    $(function() {
 $( "#element_94_datepick" ).datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
    }
    });
    });

As soon as I plugged that in, it solved the problem.